# What does this do in JavaScript: array[n] = true;

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers, generator

I have the below code that generates non repeating random numbers for a bingo card.
For you to understand, I am also putting HTML code of the same:

```
window.onload = newCard;
var usedNums = new Array(76);


function newCard() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        for (var i=0; i<24; i++) {
            setSquare(i);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support this script");
    }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare) {
    var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
    var colPlace = new Array(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4);
    var colBasis = colPlace[thisSquare] * 15;
    var newNum;

    do {
        newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;
    }
    while (usedNums[newNum]);

    usedNums[newNum] = true;
    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
}
```

==================================================================================

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Make Your Own Bingo Card</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="script.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Create A Bingo Card</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="20%">B</th>
        <th width="20%">I</th>
        <th width="20%">N</th>
        <th width="20%">G</th>
        <th width="20%">O</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square0">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square7">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square9">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square11">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="free">Free</td>
        <td id="square12">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square13">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square14">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square15">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square16">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square18">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square19">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square21">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square22">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="square23">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="script.html" id="reload">Click here</a> to create a new card</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it correct that, "while (usedNums[newNum]);" is checking whether a number exists in the array?
Is that correct that, "usedNums[newNum] = true;" is setting the item in the array to a non-zero value?

If the above two questions are correct, then I am wondering, how is it generating non-repeating random numbers?

If I make "usedNums[newNum]" to false, it generates repeating numbers, can you please explain the backend functionality of this statement?

If convenient, also paste the reference links, I want to study in detail about this.

Comment: Possibly of interest to you: http://phrogz.net/tmp/7x7_random.html Just calculate all the numbers, then [shuffle them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), and then draw them out in shuffled order.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain what happens in chunks.

First the variable `newNum` is declared:

```
var newNum; //The value is undefined
```

Then a `do-while`-loop is used. To keep it short the main benefit of the `do-while`-loop is that it will always be executed at least ones. You can read about the `do-while`-loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while).

```
do {
    //This will run at least ones.
    newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;
} while (usedNums[newNum]); //Here we check if the new number is all ready used.

usedNums[newNum] = true;
```

To explain the above snippet I'm going to use an example:

1. The loop runs the first time and the number 3 is generated so `newNum = 3`.
2. The loop conditional is checked, meaning we check if the value at `usedNums[3]` is `true`.
3. Because it's the first time we generate a number `usedNums[3]` is `undefined` which evalutes to `false` - this means the the loop exits.
4. We now set the value of `usedNums[3]` to `true` indicating that the number has been used.
5. We try to generate a new number.
6. The loop runs the first time and again it generates 3 as the new number.
7. The loop conditional is checked and because `usedNums[3]` is now true, the loop runs again.
8. This time the loop generates 56 and repeats step 2-4 with the number 56 instead of 3.

I hope this clarifies what is going on in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is correct.
Because Javascript is a weakly typed language, you can do cross-type comparisons.
If an object is *not* undefined, and you do a boolean comparison on it, it will return `true`.
(the opposite also applies)

Since `true` is not `undefined`, the second statement is also correct.

The reason you get repeated numbers if you turn `usedNums[newNum]` to false, is also related to this.
The following while loop (which assigns the random numbers) is only executed *once* when `usedNums[newNum]` equals `false` or `undefined`

```
 do {
        newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;
    }
    while (usedNums[newNum]);
```

for the rest,  this isn't exactly rocket science.
If you want to know how it generates random numbers, look at `function getNewNum` (because it's doing exactly that using Javascript's `Math.random()` function)

To get a better understanding of what "weakly typed" means, i suggest [this wikipedia article on weakly typed vs strong typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)